# why on refresh react router is not working?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I am new to react and i am using react-router-dom for routing in application.

My app.jsx file is :

```
import React from "react";
import Home from "./Home";
import { Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { history } from './history';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    history.listen((location, action) => {
    });
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="row mt-5">
        <Router history={history}>
          <div>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <Link to="/Home">Home</Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <hr />
            <Route exact path="/Home" component={Home} />
          </div>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  };
};
export default App;
```

and my history.js is

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export const history = createBrowserHistory();
```

It works fine but on refresh it shows an error.Please suggest me what i am doing wrong.

Error

> Cannot GET /routeName

Comment: As I see from your code there is no route for `/routeName`, only a route to `/Home`

Comment: You probably don't need to manually create `history`. Why not just use [BrowserRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter) that creates history automatically?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky i am using react router v4

Comment: @lellefood just as example

Comment: @hu7sy [BrowserRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter) is React Router v4 (react-router-dom)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a react related question, but a server one. If you are using webpack server - see historyApiFallback parameter, else set up your server to redirect all requests to your index page

Comment: i have add

    devServer: {
            historyApiFallback: true
        }  in webpack.config.js

Answer (score 1):

install webpack-cli to enable fallback to you app on refresh.

then add `--history-api-fallback` in your dev script:

```
"dev": "webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.config.js --hot --history-api-fallback"
```

PS I wrote dev script just to clarify things.